# recursive call only for the key values present in internal_dep or skip the ones present in skip list

Tags: python

I have the following code which recursively calls each value in internal_dep,is there a way the function call can be changed to call only for the keys present in internal_dep or skip the call for the ones in skip list?

```
internal_dep = {'313115': ['313113'], '313117': ['313115'], '313137': ['313136'], '313136': ['313119'], '313119': ['313118'], '313118': ['313117']}
mainlist = ['313137', '317152' , '314449']
skip = ['313113']

def _getdep(item):
    local_list, temp_list = [], []
    temp_list.extend(internal_dep[item])
    local_list.extend(temp_list)
    for new_item in temp_list:
        local_list.extend(_getdep(new_item))
    return local_list

build_dep_list = []
for item in mainlist:
    build_dep_list.append(item)
    build_dep_list.extend(_getdep(item))

print build_dep_list
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    build_dep_list.extend(_getdep(item))
  File "test.py", line 10, in _getdep
    local_list.extend(_getdep(new_item))
  File "test.py", line 10, in _getdep
    local_list.extend(_getdep(new_item))
  File "test.py", line 10, in _getdep
    local_list.extend(_getdep(new_item))
  File "test.py", line 10, in _getdep
    local_list.extend(_getdep(new_item))
  File "test.py", line 10, in _getdep
    local_list.extend(_getdep(new_item))
  File "test.py", line 10, in _getdep
    local_list.extend(_getdep(new_item))
  File "test.py", line 6, in _getdep
    temp_list.extend(internal_dep[item])
KeyError: '313113'

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
['313115', '313113', '313117','313137','313136','313119','313118','313117']
```

Comment: You mean call only the ones that are in `mainlist` and skip keys that are in `skip` list?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - yes,call the ones in the mainlist and its dependencies ,only the keys mentioned in internal_dep

Comment: See my edited solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would modify the _getdep function to something like this:

```
def _getdep(item):
    final_dep = []
    dep = internal_dep.get(item, [])
    final_dep.extend(internal_dep.get(item, []))
    for i in [d for d in dep if d not in skip]:
        final_dep.extend(_getdep(i))
    return final_dep
```

For the use of internal_dep.get(item, []) see: http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get (it returns either the value of internal_dep[item] or if there is no such key an empty list)
**Output:**

```
['313137', '313136', '313119', '313118', '313117', '313115', '313113', '317152', '314449']
```

Comment: - thanks for your inputs..but my output is correct,in your output "313113" is missing..still need that to be printed...

Comment: Thanks, i modify it. In your question you use `build_dep_list.append(item)`. Then '317152' and '314449' have to be in the output.

Comment: you are right in that part but your output is missing "313113"

Comment: Not anymore, I have modified it (it is the 3rd entry from the end)

Comment: how is this different from the original one you provided..i created a pastie link for the original one http://pastie.org/7732621 ...both are giving the same output/

Comment: If you use other `internal_dep` data, where something in `skip` has deps, then this deps won't be included. I thought that was what you wanted.

Comment: any deps in skip should also not be included... in short skip and its deps should be excluded..

Comment: The output from my code is exactly the same as your output, except, that there are no duplicates, the sorting is different and i have '317152' and '314449' included. '313113' is in skip, but included, because you said that before. (Why) Is that not correct?